# Thread status using GDB

Tags: c++, multithreading, debugging, gdb, crash-dumps

I created a test program for mutex using following crash condition to test the lockguard.

```
mt_loc.lock();
temp=++count/0;
mt_loc.unlock();
```

When i created two threads and ran it, I got the crash and info threads looked like below:
[image]

Info thread shows like:
[image]

I am not able to to get the status of the threads using GDB. But I can see process status through cat proc/{pid}/status

[image]

Is there a way I can get the complete thread details (status etc) using gdb ?

Comment: What kind of thread status do you mean?

Comment: You can’t get much info from a zombie process (State: Z) except for accounting info. If you don’t continue the process after it gets stopped by the SIGFPE, can you get everything  you need?

Comment: actually its not like that the process is stopped. Thread1 was exited abnormally without releasing the mutex making thread2 to wait for infinite time. so i want to check thread status (waiting\blocked etc) using gdb in current debugging session (which might go similar to crash or hang dump analysis)